# tmux: using the status options on multiple status lines

Tags: tmux

I set the 'status' option to have more than one status line visible in tmux. I then used the 'status-format' option to add different items to each status line. As an apparent consequence the other 'status' options can either no longer be applied to any of the lines, or only be applied to all lines. Is there a general syntax for users to apply the 'status' options to specific status lines?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the other status options in your status-format members, look at how the default status-format[0] does it - you can use #{E:option-name} (or T for time formats too).

Comment: I'm sorry its not clear what 'how the default status-format does it' refers to.
My current default status-line has been formatted without use of the status-format option. 

The man page says'The default builds the top status line from the various individual status options below'. 

The #{E:option-name} appears in the 'Format' section of the man page, but that does not work for me in the following form: 

set -g status-format[1] "line-1 #(load-avg.sh) '#{E:status-position top}'"

Examples of statements with nested options would really help.

Comment: Well, your question is a bit unclear. If you particularly mean status-position, then it applies to all status lines, you can't have some at the top and some at the bottom. If you mean the other options, like status-justify or status-style, you can insert them into your new status lines in the same way as the default status-format[0] does - look at the what the option is set to by default. You don't need E: for styles, only for text. For example with status-justify you might include #[align=#{status-justify}], or for status-left you might include #{E:status-left}.